# My mature friends

Tags: wordplay, password

My friends are so mature...

They played the time old prank on me of changing my password on my phone. Now I'm locked out and can't access my files.

They gave me this clue:

> A atnas devil sa a lived ta asan
>   
> rm  lwo eta ym latem mrow
>   
> A nam, a nalp, a lanac, amanap
>   
> **Ssap drow: raef fo eseht**

#### What's my (new) pass word?

Comment: Do lines 2 and 4 contain typos?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It might be:

> aibohphobia

When you read the first three phrases backwards they are:

> Palindromes:
>  - A santa lived as a devil at Nasa
>  - Mr owl ate my metal worm
>  - A man, a plan, a canal, panama
>  And aibohphobia is fear of palindromes, which explains the last phrase:
>  Pass word: fear of these

Comment: This is what I thought, but lines 2 and 4 would be wrong.

Comment: @Will really? hang on i'll correct that

Comment: @Will Yeah I read your comment and the response after I posted, but I assumed they were typos indeed

Comment: Yeah, thanks that was very quick, I can't even accept yet!

Comment: I love the fact that the fear of palindromes is a palindrome :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil There's evidence that whoever decided on the official phobia names of certain things was a jerk, seeing as the fear of long words is hippopotomonstrosesquipedaliophobia.

Comment: As distinct from aibophobia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIBO)

Answer (score 7):

Password is :

> Fear of palindromes a.k.a. aibohphobia as @Wu330 pointed out

Reasoning:

> Each line is a palindrome except that each word is in the correct position but backwards.
>  Line 1 is A santa lived as a devil at nasa.
>  Line 2 is Mr owl ate my metal worm.
>  Line 3 is A man, a plan, a canal, panama.
>  Line 4 is Pass word: fear of these

Comment: Close but your answer is a clue, not the final answer

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil looks like Wu330 got the extra step first.

Comment: you were very close so +1 for that